# Authorization of @PostConstruct with Deltaspike security module

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, authorization, postconstruct, deltaspike

I'm using the deltaspike security module for authorization on method with custom annotation.
I'm using @secured and AccessDecisionVoter to acieve that. Is working well for methods invocated form the view (el reference - getters, listeners). But I need also to perform validation on the @PostConstruct method.

Is possible to achieve this with deltaspike security module? If this is not possible with deltaspike security module there is alternative?

Comment: CDI spcification: 
    "Invocation of lifecycle callbacks by the container are not business method invocations..." (a @PostConstruct annotated method is a lifecycle callback)
    "If, and only if, an invocation is a business method invocation: it passes through method interceptors and decorators... Otherwise, the invocation is treated as a normal Java method call and is not intercepted by the container"

Comment: How can be intercepted callbacks on lifecycle methods in deltaspike security module?